# null JsonNode object saved as "null" string using H2 DB

Tags: database, h2, jsonnode

I have a DB entity, contains `JsonNode`

like this:

```
@JdbcTypeCode(3001)
private JsonNode callbackData;
```

And the scenario is `callbackData = null`

Our DB is postgres which save this field as NULL to the DB (as expected).
But in the tests we are using H2 DB which saves it as a "null" string

from application.yml:

```
 datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:db;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    username: ---
    password: ---
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
        physical_naming_strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
```

The code is simple, just JPA.save:

[image]

Is there a way to save the field as null?